# ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to type cast data but when I write `TextView clickData=(TextView) view` under onItemClick(...) logcat shows msg:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

I don't know why.

This belongs from main activity:

```
  public class ListViewForAllContact extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView myListView;
        protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listviewforallcontact);



            ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());

            Cursor mCursor= onbOfContactDatabase.phoneName();

            String[] fromFileName=new String[]{ContactDatabase.NAME};
            int[] toViewId=new int[]{R.id.textView5};
            SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

            simpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.forreading,mCursor,fromFileName,toViewId,0);
             myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            myListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    TextView clickData=(TextView) view;//becouse of this line error will come.

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), clickData.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

This is xml with ListView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is second XML file with TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That view you want to access its the RelativeLayout you show on second xml. If you want to access the TextView you have to find it on that RelativeLayout.

Instead of this

> TextView clickData=(TextView) view;

try this

> TextView clickData=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id. textView5);

I think this resolves your problem

Updated...

My suggestion is to use an Adapter

> public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Things> things;
private Context context;
private TextView yearTxtView;
private TextView weekTxtView;
private TextView extraTxtView;


public YourAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Things> things) {
    this.things = things;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.things.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.things.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView =     LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.ITEM_LAYOUT, parent, false);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your code here
        }
    });

    return convertView;


}
```

}

and on that code you have, just do this

> private YourAdapter yourAdapter;
>
> this.yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(),YourArray);
>
> myListView.setAdapter(this.yourAdapter);

Comment: why view is RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Its relative layout because that is the view that is surrounding your textview, its not getting the clicking on the textview its getting the click on that View/Cell not the item inside of it.

Comment: ok I update my Answer if its hard to understand say it but its the best way to control listviews and there items.

Comment: @Francisco Castro how can i get clicked item

Comment: on both situations you have the position (argument), so when you click on the item you know the position on the array

Comment: @ Francisco Castro is there any way to get item name??

Comment: hum... you have an array of strings when you do fromFileName.get(position) -> this is the name you want I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114433/discussion-between-francisco-castro-and-xyz-rety).

Comment: @Francisco Castro fromFileName[] is only contain name of column which i define in my activity i.i want the item

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Android compiler has become very specific. I encountered the same problem, and it is a pity because this is the kind of code that is on every sample program and [Android developer forum or guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView). The solution is to **treat the compiler** by feeding it exactly what it is asking for and in this case the **textview** (android.widget.TextView).

REMOVE the layout frame (*LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc*) around the **TextView** and trust that on inflating within the **ListView** parent widget, it will "find its way in the code world". So, set it free.

So you can define the properties of the **TextView** as you need, DECLARE the *android schema* (xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android") in the **TextView** itself. After this, the compile won't be confused and everything should compile.