# how to get item from ListView

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, android-layout, listview

I am trying to type cast data but when I write `TextView clickData=(TextView) view` under `onItemClick(...)` logcat shows msg

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` the how can I get item from `ListView` which are clicked

this belongs from `MainActivity`:

```
   public class ListViewForAllContact extends AppCompatActivity {
            ListView myListView;
            protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.listviewforallcontact);



                ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());

                Cursor mCursor= onbOfContactDatabase.phoneName();

                String[] fromFileName=new String[]{ContactDatabase.NAME};
                int[] toViewId=new int[]{R.id.textView5};
                SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

                simpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.forreading,mCursor,fromFileName,toViewId,0);
                 myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
                myListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

                myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        TextView clickData=(TextView) view;//becouse of this line error will come.

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), clickData.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
```

this is xml with `ListView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is second xml file with TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think I already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758209/classcastexception-android-widget-relativelayout-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widg/37758329?noredirect=1#comment63002709_37758329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly but i assume you would like to get your data as a `String`, rather than a `TextView` (the latter does not really make sense).

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) simpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
    String data = cursor.getString(0); // replace 0 with the desired column index

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `TextView clickData=(TextView) view;`, write this:

`TextView clickData=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);`

This is because `onItemClick` receives the whole `itemView`, and the parent in your `itemView` is a `RelativeLayout`, which cannot be cast to a `TextView`. You need to find the `TextView` within the parent `itemView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TextView tv =(TextView) ((ViewGroup) view.getChildAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its returning the parent view i.e. the `RelativeLayout`. You can instead usr this code...

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view;
TextView clickData = (TextView)rl.getChildAt(0);
```